Summation problem when using OpenMP to parrallelize C++ code
I'm trying to use OpenMP with the following C++ code:
double delta(10);
const bool parallel = true;
...
delta = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) reduction(+:delta) if(parallel)
for (unsigned short y1  = 0; y1 < ny + 1; y1++)
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < delta_directions; i++)
        for (unsigned short k = 0; k < gamma_directions; k++)
            delta += pow(I[y1][i][k] - I_old[y1][i][k], 2);
delta = pow(delta,0.5);
cout << "delta=" << delta << endl;

ny, delta_directions and gamma_directions are declared before as const unsigned short and their values are defined. I and I_old are also defined before as:
double*** I;
I = new double** [ny + 1];
for (unsigned short j(0); j < ny + 1; j++)
    I[j] = new double* [delta_directions];
for (unsigned short j(0); j < ny + 1; j++)
    for (unsigned short k(0); k < delta_directions; k++)
        I[j][k] = new double[gamma_directions]();

double*** I_old;
I_old = new double** [ny + 1];
for (unsigned short j(0); j < ny + 1; j++)
    I_old[j] = new double* [delta_directions];
for (unsigned short j(0); j < ny + 1; j++)
    for (unsigned short k(0); k < delta_directions; k++)
        I_old[j][k] = new double[gamma_directions]();

and their values are defined.
In order to make a Linux executable file, I used a shell file with the following content:
g++ -O3 -std=c++11 -fopenmp main.cpp code/*.cpp -o run.exe

Strangely, when I ran the executable file on a Linux HPC cluster server, I got delta = 0 (wrong answer).
After I deleted the command
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) reduction(+:delta) if(parallel)

I got a correct answer.
Even more strangely, It worked well when I used an executable which I prepared for Windows on my Windows PC, it worked well.
Can someone help me to understand what may cause the problem?
Edit:
When I tried to write a minimal reproducible example everything worked properly. I'm attaching the code here, but the problem is that my original code doesn't work for specific combinations of delta_directions, ny and gamma_directions.
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // file settings
    std::ofstream out("out.txt");
    std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); //redirect std::cout to out.txt
    const bool parallel = true;

    // numerical parameters
    const unsigned short gamma_directions = 32;
    const unsigned short delta_directions = 12;
    const unsigned short ny = 40;

    // initializing arrays and variables
    double delta(10);

    double*** I;
    I = new double** [ny + 1];
    for (unsigned short j(0); j < ny + 1; j++)
        I[j] = new double* [delta_directions];
    for (unsigned short j(0); j < ny + 1; j++)
        for (unsigned short k(0); k < delta_directions; k++)
            I[j][k] = new double[gamma_directions]();

    double*** I_old;
    I_old = new double** [ny + 1];
    for (unsigned short j(0); j < ny + 1; j++)
        I_old[j] = new double* [delta_directions];
    for (unsigned short j(0); j < ny + 1; j++)
        for (unsigned short k(0); k < delta_directions; k++)
            I_old[j][k] = new double[gamma_directions]();

    // calculation on I
    for (unsigned short i (0); i < delta_directions; i++)
        for (unsigned short k(0); k < gamma_directions; k++)
            I[0][i][k] = 0.5;

    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) if(parallel)
    for (unsigned short y1 = 0; y1 < ny + 1; y1++)
        for (unsigned short i = 0; i < delta_directions; i++)
            for (unsigned short k = 0; k < gamma_directions; k++)
                I_old[y1][i][k] = I[y1][i][k];

    // operations on I
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) if(parallel)
    for (unsigned short y1 = 0; y1 < ny + 1; y1++)
        for (unsigned short i = 0; i < delta_directions; i++)
            for (unsigned short k = 0; k < gamma_directions; k++)
                if (y1==1)
                    I[y1][i][k] = 3;

    // error calculation
    delta = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) reduction(+:delta) if(parallel)
    for (unsigned short y1  = 0; y1 < ny + 1; y1++)
        for (unsigned short i = 0; i < delta_directions; i++)
            for (unsigned short k = 0; k < gamma_directions; k++)
                delta += pow(I[y1][i][k] - I_old[y1][i][k], 2);
    delta = sqrt(delta);

    std::cout << "delta=" << delta << std::endl;

    // deleting dynamic variables
    delete [] I_old;
    delete [] I;
}

Then I compiled it with:
g++ -O3 -std=c++11 -fopenmp main.cpp -o run.exe

[Edit] your question with a [mcve].  We need something we can copy/paste to compile and run locally.

All that double and triple star stuff is very bad C++. Allocate a std:;vector of the total lenght, and then use ((i*n)+j)*m+k translation to a linear index. Or learn about C++23 and mdspan.

totally unrelated: rather than pow(delta,0.5); consider using sqrt(delta) a bit more obvious what your intent is and might be faster since sqrt has exactly one job and can often be more easily optimized.

Is there a performance difference between pow(x, 0.5) and sqrt(x)?  Just curious why you preferred the pow() function.

Why do you use unsigned short? It may cause overflows once the loop are collapsed, explaining the unexpected 0 result. Not to mention this is not faster to use them (in fact, int or long can be faster on mainstream CPUs). Also please note that using unsigned can decrease performance due to the wrap-arround preventing some compiler optimisation which are possible on signed integers.

By the way, how big are gamma_directions, delta_directions and ny in practice? I am not sure multiple threads are a good idea here. SIMD can help to make the loop faster (GCC will not generate a fully SIMD code without -ffast-math which can be dangerous regarding your use-case). Vectorisation alone might be enough (with better compilation flags too since the currently-generated program targets 20 years-old obsolete CPUs for sake of retro-compatibility).

Last but not least, collapsing the last loop is a bad idea since GCC generate a significantly-worst code (because multiple threads can execute it requiring additional instructions for each iteration). Combined with other issues, the resulting code is pretty bad.

@ThomasMatthews from a quick review of what little literature there is I couldn't find proof sqrt(x) was consistently faster than pow(x,0.5), but when it was faster, it was  MUCH faster.

The only comment that may explain the problem is the one from @JérômeRichard about the use of a short integer and possible overflow. All other ones are unrelated to the question...

I edited my question and added a minimal reproducible example, but this example works  properly. In my original problem only specific combinations of gamma_directions, ny and  delta_directions  doesn't work properly.

About sqrt and pow - I used pow just for arrangement because I used different powers in my code and it is more organized for me. I accept the comment about the velocity and now I changed it although this is not my problem...

about the sized of my parameters - I used the following cases in a loop:     unsigned short gauss_number_delta_options2[] = {1,2,4,6,8,10,12,16,32};
unsigned short gauss_number_gamma_options2[] = {1,2,4,6,8,10,12,16,32,64,80,100,128};
unsigned short Ny_discretization2[] = {4,5,10,20,25,40,50,80,100,120,150,200};

I compiled and run your MRE on godbolt, but couldn't reproduce your issue: https://godbolt.org/z/Ebs4858nf

32128200 > 256*256. You cannot span the collapsed iteration space with short int, as mentioned by Jerome. Just use int for the iteration variables and your problems will be gone.

Indeed I can reproduce the problem with the 32128200 with g++. When testing I switched to icx and clang before using the larger index values, and these compilers are apparently able to promote the index of the collapsed loop to a larger range (but I don't think it is required by the OpenMP specification).

The problem was solved by changing unsigned short to int. Thank you.
